# All elements in list of defined class variables get the same value when making assignments

Tags: python, class

I have defined a class called `Container` and inherits `list` to hold data from and XML file which containing debian package names, public keys, repositories and other data which is later used in the script.

I initialize a class variable as a list of this type and later in the code I want to fill it up but when assigning new values, all other already assign elements change their value to the newly assig one.

Disclaimer: I may be over complicating my code, but I'm doing it on purpose to get more practice classes.

> Class definition --> GetFromXML.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class GetFromXML2:
    """
    This is version 2 of the  class GetFromXML above.
    For description, scroll up to the beginning of code.
    """
    def __init__(self, data_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.xml')):
        self._data_path = data_path
        if self._data_path == os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.xml'):
            print('No path passed during object initialization, therefore default path shown below was used:\n{}'.format(self._data_path))
        else:
            print('A new path was passed during object initialization, the path being used is shown below:\n{}'.format(self._data_path))
        self._data = [Container]
        self._root = None
        print('Initialization complete, object fully initialized.')

    def load_data(self):
        print('Loading data from {}.'.format(self._data_path))
        self._root = ET.parse(self._data_path).getroot()
        for i, k in enumerate(self._root.iter('key')):
            self.add(i, k.attrib['install'], k.text)

    def add(self, index, install, tag):
        if index != 0:
            self._data.insert(index, Container)
        self._data[index].tag = tag
        self._data[index].install = install


class Container(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self._install = False
        self._tag = ''

    @property
    def tag(self):
        return self._tag

    @tag.setter
    def tag(self, value):
        self._tag = value

    @property
    def install(self):
        return self._install

    @install.setter
    def install(self, value):
        self._install = value
```

> main --> nubty.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""
This is the main script that runs all of my Ubuntu personalization.
"""

__version__ = 0.1

import os
import GetFromXML


def main():

    print('nubt version: {}'.format(__version__))
    print('Started running {} script.'.format(__file__))

    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(dir, 'data.xml')

    # Send path as parameter for GetFromXML to the data XML, or else it will
    # default to data.xml in the same dir as this script.
    xml = GetFromXML.GetFromXML2()
    xml.load_data()


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

[IDE snapshot during debugging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJrR.png)

**Notice variable data `self._data[idx].tag` equal to all others no matter the index.**

> XML data file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <keys>
        <key install="False">https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub</key>
        <key install="False">https://dl.sinew.in/keys/enpass-linux.key</key>
        <key install="False">https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key</key>
        <key install="True">https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc</key>
    </keys>
    <sources>
        <repository install="False" >deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main</repository>
        <repository install="False" >deb http://repo.sinew.in/ stable main</repository>
        <repository install="True" >deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib</repository>
        <ppa install="False" >ppa:webupd8team/gnome3</ppa>
        <ppa install="False" >ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq</ppa>
        <ppa install="True" >https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/</ppa>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package install="False">google-chrome-stable</package>
        <package install="False">notepadqq</package>
        <package install="False">dconf-editor</package>
        <package install="False">nfs-common</package>
        <package install="False">enpass</package>
        <package install="True">virtualbox-5.2</package>
        <package install="False">virtualbox-guest-additions-iso</package>
    </packages>
    <fstab>
        <entry install="True">#Synology NFS shares</entry>
    </fstab>
    <!--Downloads - this section is to downland files from websites that don't have apt packages-->
    <downloads>
    </downloads>
</data>
```

Comment: `Container` is the class, not a fresh instance of the class.

Comment: Also, Container's init should call list.__init__(self).

Comment: @Uri Zarfaty why is this, could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Unless there's a good reason not to, you should always call the base class's initializer when overriding __init__. It may be that list's __init__ does nothing when initializing an empty list, but your shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Container` is a class, even when it looks like a variable.  Use `Container()` to call the constructor and create a new instance of that class.  Compare:

```
>>> Container
<class __main__.Container at 0x10e338c18>
>>> Container()
<__main__.Container instance at 0x10e364440>
>>> Container == Container
True
>>> Container() == Container()
False
```

So your items in the list are all the same (the `Container` class).  Use `Container()` in both `self._data` lines and you should get separate objects with different values.

Comment: Oh snap!  Stupid mistake of mine, works like a charm now. Thank you.